# Register.php data capture wrong on some accounts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySql.

From my register.php form request for a telephone number, most numbers are captured and displayed correctly in phpMyAdmin but some are displaying the same incorrect number: 2147483647.

Any ideas what would might cause this for some accounts and not others?

Sorry if that's not very well phrased.

Comment: incorrect number means?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: use HTML tel input type https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_tel and pattern so that a user may add a proper telephone number.

Comment: also show some code!

Comment: Looks like an int overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I wasn't sure which code to show. I can't see how there would be a problem with the register.php as most registrations do not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the database column that stores the phone numbers to varchar. A telephone number, for all practical programming purposes, is not a number but a string.

2147483647 is the maximum number an integer can be in MySQL, so if you try for example to store a phone number like 3147483647 as an integer, it is set to that maximum value because it is above 2147483647.

A phone number like 1147483647 will be stored correctly, because it is below.

This phenomenon is called [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: Thanks. It was set to INT but I've changed to VARCHAR as suggested. Would an int overflow (as also commented) be the cause of the string captured being the same in a number of registrations?

Comment: I added some clarification in my answer